# Serilog : Prevent Multi Line Logs when there is an Exception

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, serilog

I am using SeriLog in my .Net Core Application where i am using custom output template to log all the exception.

I have tried to change the rendering of exception as per this page.

```
${exception:format=@}
```

But Still I see exception logs are getting generated at different line as per the stack trace. I want all the stack trace to be logged in single line.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove new lines from Message and Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49700265/remove-new-lines-from-message-and-exception)

Comment: you could use the compact json formatter if your downstreams can use that